# Find number of occurrences of a string in a sentence and put it in a table

Tags: c

I need to find the number of occurrences of a word in 3 strings. For example,
if I type the following:

```
Enter a line of text: apple sauce
Enter a line of text: is
Enter a line of text: apple sauce

Word           Occurrence
apple          2
sauce          2
is             1
```

My code so far:

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 80
#define SIZE 50

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char sentences[ROWS][COLS] = { "" };
    int counter[SIZE] = { 0 };
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", "Enter a line of text: ");
        fgets(sentences[i], COLS, stdin);
    
        sentences[i][strlen(sentences[i]) - 1] = '\0';
    }
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        char* tokens = strtok(sentences[i], " ");
    
        while (tokens != NULL)
        {
            format(tokens);
    
            tokens = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
    
    system("PAUSE");
    
    return 0;
}

void format (char* t)
{
  for (size_t i = 1; i < strlen(t); i++)
  {
    if (!(isalpha(t[i])))
    {
        t[strlen(t) - 1] = '\0';
    }
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(t); i++)
  {
    t[i] = tolower(t[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: whats the question?

Comment: my guess is that your compiler is complaining about the function format.  You have to add a declarariotn of it before main

Comment: Don't forget to include `'\n'` in `strtok(sentences[i], " \n");` to treat the trailing `'\n'` generated by the user pressing [Enter] as a delimiter..... Consider using a `struct words { char word[COLS]; size_t count }` to track the occurrences of words. Iterating over one array of struct is a lot easier than iterating over multiple arrays tied together by index.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are getting an error like this

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Warning C4013   'format' undefined; assuming extern returning int   ConsoleApplication3 C:\work\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3.cpp 58

The fix is this. Add this line

```
void format (char* t);
```

just before

```
int main()
```

c is remarkably stupid, it does not like surprises. It needs to have a declaration of everything before you are allowed to reference it. THats why those #includes have to go at the beginning , they are crammed with function declarations of stuff like printf, gets, scanf....

Answer (score -1):

if i want solve your problem it's my answer

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 80
#define SIZE 50
#define MAX_WORDS 50

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

typedef struct {
    char    Text[32];
    int     Count;
} Word;

typedef struct {
    Word    List[MAX_WORDS];
    int     Length;
} Words;

int main()
{
    char sentences[ROWS][COLS] = { "" };
    int counter[SIZE] = { 0 };
    Words words = {0};
    // get sentences
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        printf("%s", "Enter a line of text: ");
        fgets(sentences[i], COLS, stdin);

        sentences[i][strlen(sentences[i]) - 1] = '\0';
    }
    // count words
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        char* tokens = strtok(sentences[i], " ");

        while (tokens != NULL)
        {
            count_word(&words, tokens);

            tokens = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }
    // show words
    puts("Word           Occurrence");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < words.Length; i++) {
        printf("%-15s%d\n", words.List[i].Text, words.List[i].Count);
    }

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
void to_lower(char* str) {
    while (*str != '\0') {
        if ('A' <= *str && 'Z' >= *str) {
            *str = *str + 32;
        }
        str++;
    }
}
void count_word(Words* words, char* t)
{
    // to lower
    to_lower(t);
    // check word exits
    bool result = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < words->Length; i++) {
        if (strcmp(words->List[i].Text, t) == 0) {
            // found it
            words->List[i].Count++;
            result = true;
        }
    }
    // check for new word
    if (!result) {
        strcpy(words->List[words->Length].Text, t);
        words->List[words->Length].Count++;
        words->Length++;
    }
}
```